# Displaying a static block as a popup window in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display a static block in Magento as a popup window, but can't seem to get the code to work.

I've found code in various places on the internet that seems to be fairly close to what I want but I can't get any results. I've used the basic code to return the "top links" to my site so I know that the basics work.

I've created a `delpopup.php` script in my Magento root folder and put in this code:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

$layout = Mage::app()
    ->getLayout();

$layout
    ->getUpdate()
    ->addHandle('default')
    ->load();

$layout
    ->generateXml()
    ->generateBlocks();

echo '<p>before</p>';

echo $layout
    ->createBlock('cms/block')
    ->setBlockId('delivery-info')
    ->toHtml();

echo '<p>after</p>';
?>
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't display the static block. That part of the output is blank.

The idea is that I can place a link in a regular page in Magento and have my delivery into pop up. Like this:

```
<a title="" onclick="popWin('http://www.mysite.com.au/delpopup.php', 'deliveryinfo', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" href="#">Delivery Info</a>
```

Basically I want to be able to display a static block in a popup window that uses my Magento site's theme. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of your static block? Your codes looks ok for me.

Comment: @ivantedja - It's just some plain HTML. It's a table of delivery estimates to each post code from our warehouse.

Comment: Did the echo before and after shown up on the pop up?

Comment: That's weird, have you tried changing it into another block id? eg: footer_links

Comment: @ivantedja - Well I feel foolish. I was using the wrong static block id. Using `footer_links` worked - and so it did when I used the right id for my static block. However the theme didn't work. I just got plain html for both. Not quite yet what I need.

Comment: You can also try out this extension to call static block in popup window anywhere on the website - http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/popup-splash-screen.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I thought, the problems lies on incorrect `Block Id`.
Now that the cms is able to be shown.

So now the question is: how to get the theme work?

Not really sure what do you mean by theme, if what you mean is css that was included in `<default>` tag, you can use:

`Mage::getDesign()->setTheme('your theme');`

`echo $layout->getBlock('head')->toHtml();`

After the xml has been finished generated, it means put that code after:

```
$layout
    ->generateXml()
    ->generateBlocks();
```

Comment: Excellent. After I added your code and a `<div class="special-content">` to surround the body HTML it worked like a treat! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first setup a controller and block(s) to render the type of layout that you want to throw within the popup.  So, instead of doing this within a standalone php file, do it within the regular mage framework within a specific controller action.

Then, once you have that working - the question is how to pull it into a popup.  I'd go with maybe a nice jquery popup widget that allows you to specify a URL to hit - and then just pass in the one that you prepped for step 1 above.

You may want to look at `adminhtml/default/default/template/popup.phtml` for inspiration.  That's actually a popup template for the admin, not the frontend, but you can see what they've done.

They're pulling in some standard magento blocks including the `head` block, which should pull in all your CSS and JS, in order to give you the general color scheme / look&feel of your frontend, but without all of the navigation, etc.

Comment: Eeek! That's beyond the my level of expertise in Magento. Your answer does sound plausible, but I won't know where to start. Also, would this approach end up with a window without the "chrome" of the normal Magento page? I just want the static block content not the headers, footers, etc.

Comment: If you don't want headers, footers ... you need to set a different template for your block.

Comment: Updated with a little more detail, ya I think @Francesco is right a separate template for the popup would probably be good.